# Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 3803 pos 12: '_history.isNotEmpty': is not true

Tags: flutter

> i used **persistent_bottom_nav_bar**  library in my app. When i use Navigator  to display a new screen then error show.

```
InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName("previousjob"));
      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        CupertinoPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return SettingMenu();
          },
        ),
        (_) => true,
      );
    },
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I'm also facing same issue in `persistent_bottom_nav_bar`.

Answer (score 16):

I solved the issue in my code. My issue is that I was called navigator pop twice in a particular situation which caused the error.

Answer (score 6):

This is my 1st answer so might not be very clear. But from what I understood while having this same problem is, you need to use `push` first before you can actually use `pop`.

You are using `pop` first so there is nothing into your history.

Try:

```
    InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNameed(ModalRoute.withName("previousjob"));
          Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            CupertinoPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return SettingMenu();
              },
            ),
            (_) => true,
          );
        },
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was because I tried to call `pop` after I have called `pushAndRemoveUntil`. After I remove the above-mentioned `pop` it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved! In my case, I was using this:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute())
```

I changed to this:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute())
```

Answer (score 1):

This happen when your route stack is empty.
just befor call  `pop()`, check it that `capPop()` or `maybePop()` return **true**.